# javascript variables and functions

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment that i need to do however  I am not able to get in touch with my teacher for the next 3 days cuz of a holiday. It needs to be finished before I go back. I am NOT an expert nor anywhere near one in javascript. I am taking classes and we arent all the way finished talking about this assignment but my teacher always gives extra credit to those who can figure out a problem before we finish talking about it.

-INSTRUCTIONS-

You will need to create some variables
and functions to calculate the total cost for individual
pizza orders and calculate the Grand Total for all orders.
Use the following values for the calculations:

- A large pizza costs $10
- The Tax Rate is 8.25%
- The delivery tip is outlined below by the customer
- Use the random() method to generate the range of tip % paid by the customer, where indicated.
- Format all amounts to 2 decimal places

  1. Customer 1 orders 5 large pizza's and pays a 10% delivery tip
  2. Customer 2 orders a random number of pizza's (between 1–25) and pays a random
     delivery tip (between (0%-25%)

     ## Simple Pizza Order!

  var grandTotal = 0;

  ```
         var pizzaCost = 10;

         var taxRate = .0825; 

         var tipRate = .10; 

         quantity = 5;

         var subTotal = pizzaCost * quantity 

         var tipAmount = subTotal * taxRate 

        var taxAmount = subTotal * taxRate 

        var total = subTotal + tipAmount + taxAmount 

        grandTotal + = total;
  ```

This is what i have so far. How do i make costumer 1's order show up on the page with the calculations and all that?  I got this far but the rest is stumped me.

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: It also seems like you're mixing html with javascript which won't work unless its in a `<script>` tag

Comment: Sorry I was trying to format it right. I know I need script tags.  but when I put them on there they dont show up.  so basicly i put from var grandtotal to grandtotal in between script tags. what else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Calculate() {
  var pizzaCost = Number(document.getElementById('PizzaCost').value);
  var tax = Number(document.getElementById('TaxRate').value);
  var tip = document.getElementById('Tip').value;
  tip = Number((tip.substring(0, tip.length - 1)));

  var result = pizzaCost + (pizzaCost * tax) + (pizzaCost * (tip / 100));
  console.log({
    pizzaCost: pizzaCost,
    tax: tax,
    tip: tip,
    total: result
  });
  
}

function GenerateTip() {
  document.getElementById('Tip').value = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) + "%");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Simple Pizza Order</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Pizza Cost:
      <input type="text" id="PizzaCost">
    </p>

    <p>Tax Rate:
      <input type="text" id="TaxRate">
    </p>

    <p>Delivery Tip:
      <input type="text" id="Tip">
      <input type="button" value="Generate Tip" onClick="GenerateTip();">
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="Calculate();">
    </p>

    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you however we are supposed to use the information he gave us. since this isnt a Jquery class I dont think he will accept this lol. BUT thank you for answering me

Comment: Javascript only now. But seriously, get onto JQuery ;)

Comment: how is jquery easier to understand? I don't understand why anyone would need jquery to make computations

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2010/08/27/top-8-reasons-why-jquery-is-so-popular.aspx

In particular point 3 for someone new to web dev. You don't need to ever use Jquery, as it is a wrapper for Javascript, but the syntax is much cleaner, and easier to pickup and easier to debug.